# What is the problem of raspbian boot error?

Tags: boot

I have a raspberrypi3.

I downloaded the latest raspbian Jessie with desktop. (July 5, 2017, kernel ver 4.9)

The SD card was normally formatted using the SDForamtter,

[image]

and the img file was normally created using the ImageWriter

[image]

In this way, version 2016 of Raspberrypi is booted up, and now with the current version, the following error message appears when booting.

[image]

[image]

Did I make a mistake?
Or how can I solve this problem?

I tried again, but unfortunately I get the same error.

Comment: Are you sure you correctly formatted the card? As the error message indicates the boot and root partitions are not on the same device. Are you burning the card on a mac or windows?

Comment: i have windows7 64bit.  The format and img file installation photos have been updated with additional questions.

Comment: You can skip the format part and just use win32diskimager. why do you have what appear to be Asian chars. on some screens but the interface is in English?

Comment: I am Asian (that is, Korean).
So the Windows OS is also a Hangul system.
The img file is located under the folder name in Asian language. Is this a problem?

Comment: No I was just curious about the mixed language. Refer to this for the proper steps https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/installation/installing-images/windows.md

Comment: Is the microSD card formatted as FAT32?

Comment: there are two partitions one (the smaller) and the only one you can view easily from Win is a fat partition.

Comment: I tried again, but unfortunately I get the same error.

Comment: Have you tried doing what the error says? Namely, finish booting and then run raspi-config and resize from there.

Comment: Does it mean to increase the size in raspi-config?

Comment: in raspi-config there is an option to expand the filesystem, it is under advanced options.

Comment: If I click OK on the error screen above, it reboots again and the above screen reappears. So I can not configure it on the GUI screen. Sorry, can you open the config.txt file and tell me how to fix it?

Comment: I would try a new download of the image and a new SD card

Comment: Yes, thank you. If you find the same symptom or new solution, I would appreciate your advice.

Comment: I downloaded the new Raspbian and found that the files I downloaded were different in capacity. Perhaps it seems that Raspbian has been downloaded incompletely. After that, the image was successfully installed, image burning succeeded, and it booted well. Thank you. Have a nice day.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A number of people have had problems with this image. See https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?p=1186262#p1186262

The image has a size 4661483821 (which looks odd), and causes problems with some imaging programs, which discard the incomplete block.

I do not know if this is your problem, but suggest you check the checksum of the download, and if OK try one of the supported imaging programs.

See [installing-images](https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/installation/installing-images/README.md)

PS There is no need to format the card if using an imager program.

Comment: Thanks for the good info.
I downloaded the new Raspbian and found that the files I downloaded were different in capacity.
Perhaps it seems that Raspbian has been downloaded incompletely.
After that, the image was successfully installed, image burning succeeded, and it booted well.
Thank you. Have a nice day.

Answer (score 0):

Download it again. I had experienced it. The image size is wrong.
I downloaded it again. Then, the image booted successfully.